# SSRS: Snapshot runtime?

Tags: reporting-services, snapshot

I have a SSRS report which is the snapshot or another report. It runs every day @ 6 am. I want to add a header at the top of the report(snapshot), which indicates when the snapshot was taken so that the user knows when the snapshot was taken.

Does anyone know how can i do that?

Comment: what is your purpose. please give more details.

Comment: do you want add the current date or time that report is processing?

Comment: i want to add the time when the snapshot was run?

Comment: what is a snapshot? snapshot from db?

Answer (score 0):

if I truly understand your question :

you can add date or time of report processing by adding a textbox on header and write this expression as its value :

```
=TimeOfDay()
```

or

```
=Now()
```

Comment: My understanding of the question was that they wanted to know the age of the data in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ususally you would use Globals!ExecutionTime to display this, but from my research, headers and footers are calculated when the report is rendered.  A work around for this is to place the textbox (make it hidden) with Globals!ExecutionTime in it on the report body and then place another textbox in the header or footer which references that textbox like this: ReportItems!**ReportBodyTextBoxName**.Value.

Answer found on the following site:

http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=52186

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me was to add an extra column to my dataset. e.g.:

```
SELECT COL1
      ,COL2
      ,...
      ,COLn
      ,SYSDATE AS EXEC_DAT
FROM ...
```

You can then use `First(Fields!EXEC_DAT.Value, "DATASET_NAME")` if the expression is in the header.

PS: SYSDATE works for Oracle, you'll have to determine the correct function for your RDBMS